# how to convert an executable file into a c++ file to peak at code

Tags: c++, type-conversion, exe

I have an executable file, which was developed in c++. How do I convert it back into c++? I am unsure where to start. I am trying to edit a game, so that the ai makes decisions faster.

Comment: The short answer is: you can't.

Comment: Here's an analogy: I hold a can of coca-cola. How do I convert that can into the blueprint for the factory that made it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to add,  you can't but you can disassemble it.  With OllyDBG or IDA pro...  You have to have a good grasp of Assembly language.

Then debug the game....  And watch the registers and watch what instructions make the game slow.

Comment: This will only help you debug the game, this will not allow you to edit the game to make it run better. You need to recompile the game's original source code in order to do that, which you are not likely to have unless you are writing your own game, or using an open-source game.

Comment: That gets you as far as an assembly-code like view, not C++. Going all the way back to C++ requires interpreting that code and writing something equivalent in C++ manually.